# Beamer buttons change zoom in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: beamer, hyperref, pdf

I am using Beamer to create slides (the editor I'm using is Bakoma Tex). I can add buttons to go back and forth between slides using the \hyperlink command. When I open the slides as pdf (in Adobe Acrobat Professional 8), the buttons appear and work as intended; but when I press on them, the zoom in the destination slides changes. This messes up full screen views.

I presume it is an issue of the settings in the viewer, but I need to fix this isue and I have no idea how to do it. Here is a short example of what I have:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,serif]{beamer}

\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}

\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]

\begin{document}

\title{My Example}

\begin{frame}

  \titlepage

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\label{back again}

\frametitle{Slide 1}

\begin{itemize}

\item

Starting point. \hyperlink{there}{\beamergotobutton{To Slide 2}}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\label{there}

\frametitle{Slide 2}

\begin{itemize}

\item

Ending point. \hyperlink{back again}{\beamerreturnbutton{To Slide 1}}

\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX stackexchange. I have reformatted your question to suit the formatting style of TeXSX. You can indent the entire code by marking it and pressing the `{}` button. Enjoy your stay here! :)

Comment: When compiled with MikTeX2.9 it then views without that problem in Adobe Reader 8.0.  So, knowing nothing about how Bakoma TeX sets up the pdf compile, you may need to research the settings in Bakoma TeX.

Comment: Thanks! I tried MikTeX2.9 and it worked fine, so it should be something with my Tex editor after all. I'll look into it.